# Is there a way to get a callback when Ember.js has finished loading everything?

Tags: ember.js

I am building an Ember.js app and I need to do some additional setup after everything is rendered/loaded.

Is there a way to get such a callback? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are also several functions defined on Views that can be overloaded and which will be called automatically. These include `willInsertElement()`, `didInsertElement()`, `afterRender()`, etc.

In particular I find `didInsertElement()` a useful time to run code that in a regular object-oriented system would be run in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. The last didInsertElement call is really the callback I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `ready` property of `Ember.Application`.

example from http://awardwinningfjords.com/2011/12/27/emberjs-collections.html:

```
// Setup a global namespace for our code.
Twitter = Em.Application.create({

  // When everything is loaded.
  ready: function() {

    // Start polling Twitter
    setInterval(function() {
      Twitter.searchResults.refresh();
    }, 2000);

    // The default search is empty, let's find some cats.
    Twitter.searchResults.set("query", "cats");

    // Call the superclass's `ready` method.
    this._super();
  }
});
```

Comment: Is the Ember version of $(window).load()? I want to preload some images after the App is ready.

Answer (score 5):

LazyBoy's answer is what you want to do, but it will work differently than you think. The phrasing of your question highlights an interesting point about Ember.

In your question you specified that you wanted a callback *after* the views were rendered. However, for good 'Ember' style, you should **use the 'ready' callback which fires after the application is initialized, but *before* the views are rendered.**

The important conceptual point is that after the callback updates the data-model you should then **let Ember update the views.**

Letting ember update the view is mostly straightforward. There are some edge cases where it's necessary to use 'didFoo' callbacks to avoid state-transition flickers in the view. (E.g., avoid showing "no items found" for 0.2 seconds.)

If that doesn't work for you, you might also investigate the 'onLoad' callback.

Comment: Hi jdar, about the 'didFoo' callbacks, how do you use it? Because my view is printing an object, but when the view is rendered the object is not loaded in the store yet. So i would like to know in my view, when the object has been rendered in my template...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jQuery ajax callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) for this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){ console.log("ajax started")})
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){ console.log("ajax stopped")})
```

This will work for all ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

I simply put this into the Application Route

```
actions: {
    loading: function(transition, route) {

        this.controllerFor('application').set('isLoading', true);

        this.router.on('didTransition', this, function(){
          this.controllerFor('application').set('isLoading', false);
        });
    }
}
```

And then anywhere in my template I can enable and disable loading stuff using {{#if isLoading}} or I can add special jQuery events inside the actual loading action.

Very simple but effective.