# Is there any Ember event similar to `onload`

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, discourse

I want to execute JavaScript when all content (e.g. images) has been loaded in my Ember application.

I already tried using `didInsertElement()` and `didRender()` hooks, but it looks like they do not wait for background images to load.

Here's what my component's code snippet looks like:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() {
      this._super(...arguments);
      Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
        var home =$('#main-outlet')[0];
        home.className += " homePage";
        startTimer(5);
      });
    },
});
```

Any solution or an alternative approach for this?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385578/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-callback-when-ember-js-has-finished-loading-everything)

Comment: What do you want to achieve by adding the className `homePage`? Can you not fix this problem within your template?

Comment: I want to start the css animation when page is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember does not have an event that is equivalent to `onload`.

However, regarding an alternate approach, you could leverage Ember’s alias for jQuery, in combination with the `didInsertElement` hook within your component, to achieve the order of execution that you are looking for. Try this:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    Ember.$(window).on('load', this.executeCssAnimations);
  },

  executeCssAnimations() {
    // your CSS and animation logic would go here
    Ember.$('.big-background')
         .text('NOW READY FOR CSS and ANIMATION UPDATES.')
         .css('color', 'yellow');
  },

  willDestroyElement(...args) {
    this._super(...args);
    Ember.$(window).off('load', 'window', this.executeCssAnimations);
  },
});
```

The `willDestroyElement` hook has been included as well, to show proper teardown and removal of the `load` event listener from `window`.

I’ve created an [Ember Twiddle example](https://ember-twiddle.com/27f966bc8103b827f290dac50640862c?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) to demonstrate this for you.

Comment: `didRender` gets called on every re-render, which can happen a lot of times and you probably don't want to assign a load listener every time a render happens. You only want to do it when the component is first inserted into the DOM, i.e. in `didInsertElement`. You might also want to remove it in `willDestroyElement`

Comment: @nem035 Thanks for the good code review - updated with those refactors.